# Make Toplink event-listener-class CDI aware

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-6, toplink

We are using Toplink 11 (no JPA) as the persistence framework for our Java EE app.
In the Toplink configuration file `sessions.xml` we have defined a listener class:

```
<event-listener-class>my.application.EventListener</event-listener-class>
```

This works well, but now I'd like to inject dependencies into this listener class via CDI `@Inject`.

Not really surprisingly, this doesn't work, the injected objects are `null`. Probably because Toplink instatiates the listener class by itself, bypassing the CDI lifecycle.

Is there a way to have the listener class withing the CDI lifecycle?
Alternatively, can I manually "inject" CDI managed beans into a class, e.g. in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to use CDI within EntityListener was [introduced with JPA 2.1](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#CDI_Entity_Listeners).

According to [this guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/jpa-082702.html), JPA 2.1 can be enabled since TopLink 12.1.3. Would it be possible to upgrade your environment to that version?

Alternatively, it might be enough to simply update bundled eclipselink.jar file to newer version.

It might also be worth taking a look at [Apache CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) or [JBoss Seam](http://seamframework.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Upgrading Toplink is not possible at the moment. CODI and Seams seem to focus on JSF and the web stack. We are using Java EE with EJBs and remote invocation without a web layer.

Comment: In that case, have you attempted upgrading to a newer version of eclipselink.jar? I am not able to verify that at the moment but that should be backwards compatible with the old version of TopLink that you are using.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind as a solution, thanks. Major version changes in such core libraries have to be handled carefully here (testing, ...)